# How to set something to added automatically to the post

Tags: posts, customization, themes

I'm using the 2024 theme and just wanted to know if it has a feature which I can set something like a text to be added automatically after the first two or three paragraph of my posts.

The Astra theme has this feature that you can create and set a block to be automatically added anywhere in your post.